# Why does my bootstrap modal popup not close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

```
 $('#popup').modal('hide');
```

I am trying use this code to close my modal, but it doesn't close.
I wrote this in my ts `import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";`.
[My Imports in html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0yOO.png)
What can I do to get it working?

Comment: What version are you using? Bootstrap 5 or 4?

Comment: @KevinMahrous I use 5

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#methods) again to read the right implementation. Also, it looks like you are using Bootstrap 5. You are writing the `hide()` for older bootstrap versions.